# How to design user input form in php

Tags: php, html, validation

I am developing website for a company in **php**. In website, i m making user input form. 
I just want to know is it good to write **logic and html code** in one php file or not. when i use seperate pages.. one for html code and another php logic. 
I faced problem in **validating form**. 
I am validating form using both ways i.e. javascript and php. javascript is ok. but for php.. validation is little bit difficult. when errors occures, **how it goes to html page to show errors after validating on server side?**

Comment: It's generally a good practice to separate business logic from view, i.e. using MVC pattern. For example, in most simple case you'll have one php file for controller, from which another php file is called to be used as view (some data from controller could be passed to view as well). In view file you'll have a form, submission of which would lead to passing parameters to same controller. In this controller you can check, whether form parameters were passed, and if yes, you can validate them as you wish. You can pass extra data to view (like error messages) if some parameters are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to keep HTML and logic separate where possible. Displaying errors can be accomplished using session data. For instance:

form.php:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['form']['error']['email'])){ ?>
    <b>Error:</b> <?=html($_SESSION['form']['error']['email'])?>
  <?php } ?>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<?php unset($_SESSION['form']['error']);
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
  if($_POST['email'] == ''){
    $_SESSION['form']['error']['email'] = 'Email is required';
  }
  if(!empty($_SESSION['form']['error'])){
    // There was an error
    header('Location: form.php');
    die;
  }
  // No errors, handle the data, then redirect user to success.php:
  header('Location: success.php');
```

Remember to `require` a config file before loading these pages:

config.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  function html($str){
    return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES);
  }
```

Note that this is a simplified example, and you should use functions to make the `$_SESSION` code more accessible.

Another benefit of separating HTML and logic is that the user will not be asked if they would like to resubmit the form when reloading the form.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript validations, you can use alert() provided in javascript to show error in the same page but if you want to show error generated on php validations then you can use redirect with error variable i.e

```
header("location:filldetails.php?error=".$error);
```

where **your-url.com** is the page address in your project

**error**   is the variable name through which u can get the generated error

**some_error** is the generated error

Now, after sending error to the previous page, its to get it

```
if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
   echo $_GET['error'];
}
```

Comment: javascript validation is not problm

Comment: this answer is basically irrelevant

Comment: @Mohit u asked for how to show php validation error on html page  and thats one of the ways to do it.

Comment: OK, it makes sense, to `echo` the error, although I'd rather not use `alert()` popups to show errors. Also, I'd store the error in a PHP variable/string instead of passing it as a GET query.

Comment: @AlexanderDyachkov i guess OP asked how to show error from another php page to form submission page, if not my mistake

Comment: @Agostino alert() i suggested for showing errors generted in JS validations which is basic othervise there are other ways also to show it on HTML page

Comment: This code is not working. if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
   echo $_GET['error'];
}

Comment: in action page,, i used header("Location: filldetails.php?error = $error");

Comment: @Mohit see updated header code and let me know it you need some other help :)

Comment: You shouldn't put errors in the URL. Aside from the obvious security issues, URLs can only contain a limited number of characters. There really is no reason to use $_GET for errors.